# ValidationError with Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, model-view-controller, passport.js

I'll preface this by mentioning that I am very new to programming, node, js, and especially passport/authentication in general. I have searched relentlessly and found similar issues on stack but am unable to formulate a solution based on the answers I found. I apologize if my for the lengthy question and if it breaks any SO etiquette.

I know the user input values are correctly being passed from the ejs form to my my authController function (I can log each in the console through req.body...). I also know my database is working properly as I have accessed it in other areas. One thing I suspect based on my research is that the password could be passed as an object and isn't properly serialized somehow. That being said, in my app.js file, I am sure to do the following which I believe should avoid this issue:

```
var User = require('./models/users');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: user_password: Path `user_password` is required.

 message: 'Path `user_password` is required.',
    name: 'ValidatorError',
    properties: [Object],
    kind: 'required',
    path: 'user_password',
    value: undefined,
    reason: undefined,
    '$isValidatorError': true
```

/models/users.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    first_name: {type: String, required: true, max:100},
    last_name: {type:String, required: true, max: 100},
    email_address: {type: String, required:true, max: 100},
    username: {type:String, required: true, max: 100},
    user_password: {type: String, required:true, max: 100}
  }
);

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

authController.js

```
userController.doRegister = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.user_password);
  var newUser = new User({
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email_address: req.body.email_address,
    username: req.body.username
  });
  User.register(newUser, req.body.user_password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render('register', { user : user });

    }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
      res.redirect('/');

      console.log('reached end of doregister in auth contro');
    });
  });
};
```

register.ejs

```
 <table>
            <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email Address</td><td><input type="text" name="email_address" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="username" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="text" name="user_password" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Register" ></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to handle user password in your schema (i.e. remove `user_password` in your user schema).  That is not safe since you did not hash and salt your user password, that is also the reason why you want to use **passport** library.  Since obviously you don't want to touch password hashing and salting, so please just let **passport-local-mongoose** does it for you.

Next, the real problem in your controller middleware is that you did not pass your `user` mongoose object to `req.login`. `passport.authenticate('local', (err, authUser) => { (do_something) })` is a middleware, which gives you the authenticated user object ass a call back, but it does not populate `req.user` object until you decide to "login" the user.  So you should try this instead:

```
userController.doRegister = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.user_password);

  const newUser = new User({
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email_address: req.body.email_address,
    username: req.body.username
  });

  User.register(newUser, req.body.user_password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render('register', { user : user });
    }

    req.login(user, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('reached end of doregister in auth contro');
      return res.redirect('/');
    });

  });
};
```

---

Note: Please don't use `var` since we now have `const`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response - it is very helpful.  One edit I made before it compiled as expected was to change res.logIn to req.login. It is now working, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your error is probably related to this:

```
var newUser = new User({
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email_address: req.body.email_address,
    username: req.body.username
 });
```

Here you should have to have user_password

```
var newUser = new User({
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email_address: req.body.email_address,
    username: req.body.username,
    user_password: req.body.user_password
});
```

Since this is required you cannot create a new user without it.
A better approach is to treat the password in the [before save](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#validateBeforeSave), there you hash and validate it.

Comment: Yes or no, the real login problem is not here. But you were absolutely correct, there should have a validation error since `user_password` is a required field.

Comment: The error he posted is a Mongoose ValidationError: ValidationError: User validation failed: user_password: Path `user_password` is required.

Comment: Agreed.  But that is not the correct way to address the issue.  If OP accept your answer, the problem then still be there, it is not going to login the user.  Obviously, the OP is not thoroughly understand how **passport** works, there should have no password field in the schema at all, instead it should be added by **passport-local-mongoose**.